# Queueing Operation

Tags: c#, multithreading

im sending smses using  dll, that dll have some events one  them is

Session_OnMessageAccepted

inside that im doing something like this

```
   void Session_OnMessageAccepted(object sender,EventArgs e)
     {
         new Thread(
             delegate()
                 {
                     //do stuff
                 }).Start();
     }
```

this is ok only problem is the code inside dostuff gets excuted same time , is there is any chance i can put "dostuff"in a queue and make it happen synchronously?

Comment: This is some poorly explained question. Revise!

Comment: the guy starts new thread for each event.. nuff said

Comment: @Bobb That's hardly constructive criticism. Please share your knowledge instead.

Comment: @Aliostad It's not hard to work out what the question is if you've worked with message processing. It's not *that* poor.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I know little about message and processing ;)

Comment: @Stacker I presume when you say "synchronously" you mean "serially" i.e. process one operation at a time in the order they were queued in.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`ConcurrentQueue` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the messages in the queue. And you can have a separate thread started(On App Start) which will continuously look for messages in the queue and process it.

i.e in the thread method

```
while(true)
{
    //check if the queue is empty otherwise continue;
    //fetch the element
    //process it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> A Note About The ThreadPool

As a general comment to your current code, consider using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` rather than creating new threads.

Queuing work items to the `ThreadPool` is much more efficient than creating new threads for short term tasks. The `ThreadPool` maintains a pool of existing threads and re-uses them. Creating and managing threads is expensive so should be avoided when needing many short-lived tasks. As well as being efficient, the `ThreadPool` also has natural queuing behaviour.

However, using the `ThreadPool` does not guarantee that items are executed in the order you queued them, and may also result in items being executated at the same time i.e. concurrently. Therefore the `ThreadPool` doesn't help you out for this particular quesiton.

> Example Message Processing Loop

The following is a message processing loop pattern which allows operations to be queued and then processing on a separate thread serially.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly object _syncObj = new object();
    private readonly Thread _thread;
    private readonly Queue<Action> _queue = new Queue<Action>();
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _messageAccepted = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public SomeClass()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Action operation;

                while (TryDequeue(out operation))
                {
                    operation();
                }

                _messageAccepted.WaitOne();
            }
        }) {IsBackground = true};

        _thread.Start();
    }

    private void Session_OnMessageAccepted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Action operation = () =>{/* Do stuff */};

        Enqueue(operation);
    }

    private void Enqueue(Action operation)
    {
        lock (_syncObj)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(operation);

            _messageAccepted.Set();
        }
    }

    private bool TryDequeue(out Action operation)
    {
        lock (_syncObj)
        {
            operation = (_queue.Count != 0) ? _queue.Dequeue() : null;

            if (operation == null) _messageAccepted.Reset();

            return (operation != null);
        }
    }
}
```